# SQLite/python - Adding columns with data inside while loop

Tags: python, sqlite, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a SQLite database from scraped text. Each row in the database corresponds to a string taken from a list, and for every loop another column is created and populated with new string data.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()  

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Data;
CREATE TABLE Data(
id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
words    text)''')

while True
    url = 'www.xyz.com'
    if url == "break": break

#parse - find tag of interest
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    p_s = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    words = str(p_s.findAll('p',{'id':'p-5'}))
    words = strip_tags(words)
    words = pd.DataFrame(words)

    col_number = col_number + 1
    col_name = ('Group', col_number)

    cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE Data ADD ? TEXT''', (col_name,))
    for i,j in words.iterrows():
        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Data (col_name)
        VALUES (?)''',(j))
    conn.commit()
```

When I run this code I get:

```
 sqlite3.Operational.Error : near "?": syntax error
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks, and I apologize for my sloppy code, I'm new to Python!

Comment: Adding new data as columns is terrible design. Add the "new string data" as new rows, not as new columns. Use **one** additional column `Group` to hold the `col_name` values. It'll be much easier to use the result.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
    cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE Data ADD {} TEXT'''.format('Group ' + str(col_number)))
    for i,j in words.iterrows():
        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Data ({})
        VALUES (?)'''.format(col_name), (j,))
    conn.commit()
```

or

```
cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE Data ADD {} TEXT'''.format('Group ' + str(col_number)))
        for i,j in words.iterrows():
            cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Data {}
            VALUES (?)'''.format(col_name), (j,))
        conn.commit()
```

one of those should work

Comment: Unfortunately neither are working for me. The return error is on the line:
 
`cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE Data ADD {} TEXT'''.format(col_name))`

and the error is:

`sqlite3.Operational.Error: near "(": syntax error`

Comment: try `cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE Data ADD {} TEXT'''.format('Group ' + col_number))` and see if it passes the first one

Comment: @cody Change that to `'Group ' + str(col_number)` or equivalent, else you're adding a `str` to an `int`.

Comment: Ok, thanks @alexis and cody, I've come up with a work around with your help. Instead of writing from a dataframe to the database, I wrote from a list to the database instead, and that seems to work using the above methods.

Now I'm left with a problem where each time I append the database with a new list, the new data is still attached to the primary key from the first column. So my first column has 100 elements and ends at row 99, and my second column has 150 words but starts at row 100. Any idea how to work around this? I'd like each column to start at element row 1.